# Failed to import PyMongo in Pycharm

Tags: python, flask, pycharm, pymongo

I use Pycharm to develop a flask application.
I am trying to use the PyMongo API, but got this unresolved reference in Pycharm
[image]

I am sure that PyMongo is installed:
[image]

Is there anyone can solve this issue? It is pretty annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import it this way:

```
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
```

`flask.ext` is kind of [deprecated](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/1135)

Comment: Nicely done! thank you so much! I guess the official document needs an update.

Comment: The solutions works for me, but I think you have a typo. It should be PyMongo instead of Pymongo. Thanks.